# More rigid Apple USB-C to cable

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, accessories

I own two USB C to C cables from Apple. One of which I bought about half a year ago ([this one](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLL82AM/A/usb-c-charge-cable-2-m)) and one that came with my MacBook Pro 13 (Mid 2017). I've noticed that the cable that came with the MacBook Pro has feels a lot more rigid, thicker and plugs into my devices a lot smoother than the older cable.

Does anyone know whether they updated the old USB C to C cable to this more rigid version or is it still the old one? (Or is the more rigid version exclusive to MacBook Pros?)

Comment: Apple doesn't make cables - they may have simply changed suppliers or have multiple suppliers for different products.  That said, I have never found genuine Apple accessories (adapters, cables, etc.) to be of good quality.  I usually try to find a good 3rd party supplier of these things.  For example, I just bought 2 [USB C cables](http://amzn.to/2xkQ6ye) and the build quality is fantastic - better than anything Apple sells.

Comment: The adapters and the cables are completely different stories. The cables do tend to wear out quickly because of their non-rigid design as compared to 3rd-party cables. The adapters are actually very well-engineered, much more so than 3rd-party adapters tend to be. See [this teardown](http://www.righto.com/2012/05/apple-iphone-charger-teardown-quality.html) of an Apple adapter by an engineer (especially the section "What makes Apple's iPhone charger special").

Comment: @tubedogg - the "adapters" I am referring to are things like TB3-2, or Ethernet, DVI, etc.  Power Adapters are an entirely different story and I won't use any 3rd party suppliers for power adapters.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to ensure that you will get a specific cable design (for lack of a better word) when ordering an Apple cable. I'd suggest finding a third-party cable you like and sticking with it. I personally use the Amazon Basics cables (Lightning to USB-A, not USB-C, though) and have had no issues with them. I have found them to be much more rigid and thick than the Apple cables and therefore they last a lot longer.